# How to center align a table using pdfmake and datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, pdfmake

Can I auto-align a table to the center using pdfmake? I tried a few different solutions with no results. Here's my code:

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#dt').DataTable( {
      "dom": 'Bfrtip',
      "buttons": [
       'csv', 'pdf',
      ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center align table - PDFMAKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949581/how-to-center-align-table-pdfmake)